# SSRS BIDS 2008 Parameter Date Range

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, parameters, bids

I have produced a report where the user will need to view financial years data.

So for example April 2010 - March 2011 will have one years data however if the user selects this as in my image, data for January, February, March in 2010 will be brought as well as January, Febrary and March 2011, when I dont want the Jan,Feb,Mar for 2010 as the financial year begins in April.

I therfore need to be able select a data range using parameters to stop bringing data through that I didnt ask for.

Can anyone advise me how to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can build a month-year key to use instead of your ad-hoc year and month parameters. You can then display it for example as YYYY/MM - so that you can select 2010/04 through 2011/03.

Another option would be to have from month (with year) to month (with year).

Yet another option would be to have a year, month, and number-of-months, selecting 2010, 04, then 12 for number-of-months.

Your two parameters aren't aware of eachother in the way that you want it to be.